# Need pow(-1,1.2) to be 1

Tags: c++, math, numerical-methods, pow

I am using math.h with GCC and GSL. I was wondering how to get this to evaluate?

I was hoping that the pow function would recognize pow(-1,1.2) as ((-1)^6)^(1/5). But it doesn't.

Does anybody know of a c++ library that will recognize these? Perhaps somebody has a decomposition routine they could share.

Comment: What's wrong with `-1 * abs(-1)`?

Comment: This is just an example. I plan on computing pow (-293.2834,1.2) and was hoping it would be 913.5766245.

Comment: I think this is going to be very, very hard.  1.2 is not even exactly representable as a floating point number...  I think you need to represent the exponent as a rational number (i.e., the pair 6,5), and then write your own code to do `pow(pow(x,numerator), 1/(denominator)))`.  (This will do bad things if x is negative and the numerator is odd, of course.)

Comment: maybe you can do  pow(1,1.2) and take care of (+/-)ve manually ?

Comment: It's also important to realize that 1.2 *does not exist* in floating point, so the "simplification" you want cannot happen. `1.2` yields the closest `double` to the mathematical value 1.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for `pow(abs(x), y)`.

---

Explanation: you seem to be thinking in terms of

x<sup>y</sup> = (x<sup>N</sup>)<sup>(y/N)</sup>

If we choose that N === 2, then you have

(x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>y/2</sup> = ((x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup>)<sup>y</sup>

But

(x<sup>2</sup>)<sup>1/2</sup> = |x|

Substituting gives

|x|<sup>y</sup>

This is a stretch, because the above manipulations only work for non-negative x, but you're the one who chose to use that assumption.

Comment: This is definitely the best answer so far.

Comment: @Ben: Do you mean "non-negative y"?  Because your approach works fine for positive and negative x

Comment: @Nemo: No, I mean non-negative x.  What's (-1)**1?  Now what's (-1)**2**(1/2)?  The manipulations are only valid for non-negative base, the exponent doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ben: Got it.  Except her question is assuming a negative x...  No matter what choice she makes, there are going to be some strange results

Comment: @Nemo: She's assumed that the first step works on her data... the rest of the analysis is valid, because x**2 is positive for all real x.

Comment: Yeah, I do seem to be thinking in terms of that. The problem was solved by reworking the physics and coming up with a separate signing function. So sign(x,y)|x|^y

Answer (score 12):

Mathematically, `pow(-1, 1.2)` is simply not defined.  There are no powers with fractional exponents of negative numbers, and I hope there is no library that will simply return some arbitray value for such an expression.  Would you also expect things like

```
pow(-1, 0.5) = ((-1)^2)^(1/4) = 1
```

which obviously isn't desirable.

Moreover, the floating point number `1.2` isn't even exactly equal to `6/5`.  The closest double precision number to `1.2` is

```
1.1999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

Given this, what result would you expect now for `pow(-1, 1.2)`?

Comment: cpow(-1, 1.2) is -0.809 - 0.588j, more or less.

Comment: @duskwuff: Which is a completely aribtrary choice.  For example, it's also equal to 0.3090-0.9510j).  I intentionally omitted this from my answer, because it's obviously not what the OP is talking about.

Comment: I'm on my Texas instruments calculator and with imaginary numbers I get (-1)^(1.2) equal to 1.

Comment: @Misha: That's another legal result.  Basically, `exp(1.2 * (Log(1.2) + 2 * pi * k))` with `Log` being the [principal value of the complex logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm#Definition_of_principal_value) and `k` an arbitrary integer are valid results.  For this example, there are in total 5 different results.  Setting `k=2` will give 1.

Comment: I have to disagree… exponentiation is defined over the real numbers, separately from taking the roots of a polynomial which only works over the rational numbers. Euler's identity `e^iπ+1=0` "defines" log(-1) as `iπ`, and that's the sensible definition used in engineering. OP's "ratio"nale is wrong, but so is this answer. `-1^1.2 = (e^iπ)^1.2 = e^(1.2iπ) = cos(1.2π) + i sin(1.2π)`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: The logarithm is ambiguous, and [so is exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_power_of_a_complex_number).  There is a standard choice for the logarithm, called the "principal value" and denoted by `Log` with a capital L.  There is no standard choice for powers, as evidenced by using different calculators with support for complex numbers -- they give different results for this case. One reason for not having a standard choice is the ...

Comment: ... [failure of power and logarithm identities in the complex case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Failure_of_power_and_logarithm_identities). 
Maybe I should have included all this in my answer, but after reading the question I figured the OP wasn't interested in complex solutions.  I'd also be interested in a reference how this arbitrary definition of exponentiation is used in engineering and how this can ever be useful. (And how are rational numbers relevant here?)

Comment: I was thinking of [phasors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor), but no, in that case (and its physical applications) the base is always *e*. The result of complex exponentiation is never used as a base for another exponentiation as I wrote above, sorry and thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to raise negative numbers to powers -- especially fractional powers -- use the `cpow()` method. You'll need to include `<complex>` to use it.

Comment: Note that `cpow` was added in C99.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to perform a complex power (`cpow()`) and then take the magnitude (`abs()`) of that after.

```
>>> abs(cmath.exp(1.2*cmath.log(-1)))
1.0
>>> abs(cmath.exp(1.2*cmath.log(-293.2834)))
913.57662451612202
```

Comment: So you think she wants (-1)^3 == 1 ?  :-)

Comment: Also, abs(x^y) == abs(x)^y if y is real.  So Ben Voigt's answer is better I think.

Answer (score 1):

`pow(a,b)` is often thought of, defined as, and implemented as `exp(log(a)*b)` where `log(a)` is natural logarithm of a. log(a) is not defined for a<=0 in real numbers. So you need to either write a function with special case for negative a and integer `b` and/or `b=1/(some_integer)`. It's easy to special-case for integer `b`, but for `b=1/(some_integer)` it's prone to round-off problems, like Sven Marnach pointed out.

Maybe for your domain `pow(-a,b)` should always be `-pow(a,b)`? But then you'd just implement such function, so I assume the question warrants more explanation .

Like duskwuff suggested, a much more robust and "mathematical" solution is to use complex functions log and exp, but it's much more "complex" (excuse my pun) than it seems on the surface (even though there's `cpow` function). And it'll be much slower if you have to compute a lot of pow()s.

Now there's an important catch with complex numbers that may or may not be relevant to your problem domain: when done right, the result of `pow(a,b)` is not one, but often **a few complex numbers**, but in the cases you care about, one of them will be complex number with nearly-zero imaginary part (it'll be non-zero due to roundoff errors) which you can simply ignore and/or not compute in your code.

To demonstrate it, consider what `pow(-1,.5)` is. It's a number `X` such that `X^2==-1`. Guess what? There are 2 such numbers: `i` and `-i`. Generally, `pow(-1, 1/N)` has exactly `N` solutions, although you're interested in only one of them.

If the imaginary part of all results of `pow(a,b)` is significant, it means you are passing wrong values. For single-precision floating point values in the range you describe, 1e-6*max(abs(a),abs(b)) would be a good starting point for defining the "significant enough" threshold. The extreme "wrong values" would be `pow(-1,0.5)` which would return `0 + 1i` (`0` in real part, `1` in imaginary part). Here the imaginary part is huge relative to the input and real part, so you know you screwed up your input values.

In any reasonable single-return-result implementation of `cpow()` , `cpow(-1,0.3333)` will probably return something like `-1+0.000001i` and ignore two other values with significant imaginary parts. So you can just take that real value and that's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::complex`. Without that, the roots of unity don't make much sense. With it they make a whole lot of sense.